# How to calculate the proportion of values in an array using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I have a huge array and I want to find the proportion of times that the highest number in the array by index number. So this would return:

```
np.array([
  [ [5, 2, 2], [2, 5, 10] ] 
])
array([ 0.5, 0, 0.5 ])
```

Also if the highest number is a duplicate such as [12, 25, 25] then I don't want to ignore it but include it in the count for the denominator when calculating the proportions.

I want to input a two dimensional array with inner arrays of size 3 and want to find out the distribution of max values throughout the array.

Comment: You want to count how many times the max value in a column occurs in that column then divide by the length of the column?

Comment: What you want to achieve is really not clear, so please reformulate your problem so that someone can answer.

Comment: @wwii That is correct

Comment: Why isn't the result ```array([ 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ])```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find the maximum(s) along axis zero with [numpy.amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax)
- create a boolean array where array == maximum
- Count all the True values of the boolean array along axis zero with [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum)
- find the proportion by dividing the count(s) by the number of rows in the original array - [array.shape[0]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy-ndarray-shape)